# Computing the mean of the numbers following a number, for each different number in a list. (yes, difficult to understand)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following list of numbers, which are random:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2]
```

For each number *(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)* I want to know the mean of the numbers that follow it.

Here is an example:
1 appears two times, at positions *0* and *6* in the list. 
At position *0*, it is immediately followed by the number **3** *(at position 1)* and at position *6* it is followed by the number **5** *(at position 7)*.
So 1 appears two times and is immediately followed by 3 and 5.
The mean of 3 and 5 is 4, (3+5)/2 = 4.0
**So the result for 1 is 4.**

Using the same method for 2:
2 is found at positions 4, 10 and 11 and followed by 4 and 2. The final 2 at the end of the list is discarded as it is folloewd by nothing.
**So the result for 2 is (4+2)/2 = 3.0**

If I go on with this method and present the results as a dictionary I obtain this.

```
results = {
  1: 4.0,
  2: 3.0,
  3: 5.0,   # 5/1
  4: 3.0,   # (1+5)/2
  5: 3.25,  # (5+2+4+2)/4
}
```

I need to automate this procedure in an efficient way because it is supposed to run on very long lists.
I want to solve this using pandas or numpy but I am a total beginner with these packages.
I am of course reading the documentations but they are so long that I feel like I will find a solution in two years :D
Any help, shortcut or link to the right parts of the docs would be appreciated.

The results don't have to be a dictionary. It can be anything, like for instance a new dataframe, as long as the computation is efficient, and elegant if possible.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Will `numbers` typically look like your example, that is, a bunch a small integers from 1 to N?  Or could something like `[3423234, 4, 4883, 87874, 11, 4, 348887, 10092, 876, 11, 123, 4883, 56, 4, 98]` occur?

Comment: Hi **Warren**, `numbers` can be filled with any random floating value. The accepted answer has been given by **shubhamsharma**, see just below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pandas Approach

```
s = pd.Series(numbers)
s.shift(-1).groupby(s).mean().to_dict()
```

---

```
{1: 4.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 5.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 3.25}
```

Comment: Wow I am impressed ! Thanks @shubhamsharma.
This is exactly what I wanted, elegant and using pandas. And hopefully efficient, I will test that on big lists.
I don't understand quite well the syntax as I am new to it, but the result is here. I will work my way through the documentation to get a full grasp on it.
Could you please add `import pandas as pd` to your answer so that newcomers who don't know this idiom have a fully working copy-pastable answer ?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `collections.defaultdict` and `zip` (or `itertools.pairwise` for python 3.10+):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

numbers = [1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2]

dct = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
# (Alternatively, on python 3.10+) for x, y in itertools.pairwise(numbers):
    dct[x].append(y)

dct = {k: sum(lst) / len(lst) for k, lst in dct.items()}
print(dct)
# {1: 4.0, 3: 5.0, 5: 3.25, 2: 3.0, 4: 3.0}
```

Comment: Or use `itertools.pairwise`

Comment: @mozway Oh yes! I still have habits from python 3.8...

Comment: Thanks **j1-lee** for your answer, nice pure python way of doing it ! My question was how to do it with pandas, so the accepted answer has been given by **shubhamsharma**, see just below.

Comment: @user1202026 No worries at all! I've just found out you _wanted_ to use pandas. I misread your post and thought you didn't want pandas! So my bad :)